# Epic/Legendary Badges and the Daily Limit

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-limit

If one hits the daily cap, then decides to sleep so they can do it all again the next day; then someone removes a vote, unaccepts an answer, etc, does the attained limit still count or is it only if you end the day on the +200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a badge is awarded it is not retracted, but if it is later invalidated somehow (such as from the retraction of a vote that would have caused you to hit the rep recap), you won't earn another badge for the same thing when you meet those conditions again.

That isn't relevant for Mortarboard, since you can only earn one once, but it would count for the counter towards Legendary or Epic.

**Edit**: if the rep is removed on the same day, then you wouldn't get the badge, because the rep cap badges are not calculated until EOD. (They are not awarded instantly on first hitting the rep cap earlier in the day -- you will not have counted as hitting the cap unless you are there at EOD, when the batch process to calculate these badges is run.)

Comment: The OP is asking about rep being removed on the same day, not on a later day.

Answer (score 3):

It counts.

The same way that you don't get more reputation even if you are below 200 reputation (if someone removes a vote or accepted answer), the cap is already reached for the day.

Comment: Um... You might have reached the cap, but I'm pretty sure it _doesn't_ count for badge purposes.  Otherwise I'd have a legendary already.

Comment: Are you certain you would @joel?

Comment: yes.  If you include every time I've hit it and then lost I'm somewhere up around 180.

Comment: That sounds odd, I'd love some official clarification

Comment: I'm going to hold off on the accepted status then. *summons Jeff* ;)

Comment: *sigh*... I lost my cap

Comment: Ah damn, sorry man. That's rather ironic though, all things considered.

Answer (score 1):

Once you hit the cap it's recorded and in the books.